# ifconfig command not found

Tags: linux, centos, command, ifconfig

I've just installed CentOS7 as a virtual machine on my mac (osx10.9.3 + virtualbox)
Running ifconfig returns command not found. Also running **sudo /sbin/config** returns commmand not found.
This is **echo $PATH**

> /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/robbert/.local/bin:/home/robbert/bin

Is my path normal? If not, how can I change it?

Also, I don't have an internet connection on virtual machine yet, maybe that's a factor.

Please bear in mind i'm a student and very new to certain terminology.

Comment: `bash: ifconfig: command not found` --> the command is deprecated, see [ifconfig and locate command not found, `bash: ifconfig: command not found`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631542/ifconfig-and-locate-command-not-found) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange where the question belongs.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ifconfig` exists in the `net-tools` package which may not be installed by default;

```
sudo yum install net-tools
```

When the package is installed, it will exist as `/sbin/ifconfig`.

Comment: if ifconfig does not exist how is an ip address configured to allow yum to operate?

Comment: Thank you very much, that's probably it. Although yum install returns cannot find a valid baseurl, I guess I don't have an internet connection to virtual machine. I'll look into that first. Any help on troubleshooting internet connection is also appreciated.

Comment: Perfect! Nice answer.

Answer (score 25):

I too had same problem after installation of RHEL,CentOS. Resolved with the following.
Type:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Press i key to go to insert mode. Write the following to the end of this file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

then exit Vi by press `:wq!`

At the terminal type below command to reflect our changes.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now type the command ifconfig , it should work.

Comment: perfect solution!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 25):

The `ifconfig` command has been deprecated so it is not installed by default on many new distros. The replacement is

```
ip address
```

You can write a shortcut

```
ip a
```

Very handy :)

Answer (score 4):

In some cases. Installing net-tools is not enough directly.

Try this:

```
apt install net-tools

nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add this to your bashrc file.

```
alias ifconfig='/sbin/ifconfig'
```

Save the file.

```
source ~/.bashrc

ifconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Server 20.04 you have to install it:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to (or do not intend to) connect the virtual machine to the Internet (offline installation), then it would be best to add a CD/DVD drive to the SCSI controller, and mount the CentOS ISO file to this drive. Then, inside the virtual machine, perform the following command:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

You can access packages from the ISO via:

```
cd /mnt/Packages
find . -name "net-tools"
```

You should have at least one result returning `<net-tools-filename>.rpm`, for example, `net-tools-2.0-0.22.20131004git.el7.x86_64.rpm`. Install using that rpm file:

```
yum install <net-tools-filename>.rpm
```

Type y when prompted "`Is this okay [y/d/N]:`" and submit. Once installation is complete, you should be all right when prompting for the `ifconfig` command again.

Answer (score 0):

Install nothing...

Just type sudo before ifconfig

for ex- sudo ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

If you install net-tools and the ifconfig is dispay as not found YOU CAN Creating aliases WHICH is relatively easy and quick process.

In order to do that you can use the following command:

```
alias ifconfig=/sbin/ifconfig
```

But this is not permanent is just temporary. In order to make it permanent use the following command:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then you can add here your command at the bottom

```
#My custom aliases
alias home=”ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykep.pem tecmint@192.168.0.100”

alias ll="ls -alF"
alias ifconfig="/sbin/ifconfig"
```